# Polynomially solvable or NP-complete?

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

**Problem:**

There is an even number of positive integers $a_1, a_2,...,a_n$. Determine whether there is a division into two sets of equal cardinality $A_1$ and $A_2$ so that the sum of the numbers from  $A_1$ is strictly greater than the sum of the numbers from  $A_2$, and the difference in the sums (from the larger take the smaller) does not exceed y, where y is the given number, y$\geq$0.

Is the problem polynomially solvable or NP-complete?

**Attempts:**

I have tried to reduce this problem to the Partition problem but my attempt failed. 
Is this task polynomially solvable?